# Python for circular filter/window on a 2D matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, filtering, windowing

I want to create a code that is able to filter in a circular manner. I have this data that I need to filter in order to make it possible for me analyze the data.

For example, I have this data

```
data=[[1,1,1,1,1],
      [2,2,2,2,2],
      [3,3,3,3,3],
      [4,4,4,4,4],
      [5,5,5,5,5]]
```

I only managed to use scipy's filter, however it only works for array/multiarray. it does it line by line. so it will only make the output shaped like a box or a bell. I need to make it circular/donut.

I only managed to do it until this far.

```
data=[[0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,2,2,2,0],
      [0,3,3,3,0],
      [0,4,4,4,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Is there any way I can implement a circle matrix as a filter, making everything else valued 0 yet making the inside of the circle valued as it is?

I want to have this kind of output.

```
data=[[0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,2,0,0],
      [0,3,3,3,0],
      [0,0,4,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

and if possible, can I make it control the thickness of the circle so that I can have a donut filter like this end product

```
data=[[0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,2,0,0],
      [0,3,0,3,0],
      [0,0,4,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The question that I asked myself is: "What is a circle?". If you always only handle 5*5 shaped objects you could define a strict form, but if you handle any other size, you will have to define, what "circle" actually means...

Comment: The circle is a perfect circle even in [200 by 500] matrix or [200 by 200] matrix the circle is still the same being in the middle of the matrix. Using the concept of (pi*r^2)

Comment: Maybe I'll reask the question. Is #1 oder #2 the circle you want? And which thickness would you assicocialte with them? https://pastebin.com/sXC2U1Jt

Comment: I'd suggest you write a function that creates the circle with 0 and 1's and then just iterate over your original matrix, keeping the value if 1, and disregards it when 0. Doing it in this manner reduces your problem to "What is a circle".

Comment: Right now I am using 200x200 matrix, and the size of the circle needs to be at the center and adjustable size & thicknes. I was planning to do element multiplication over the circular matrix (like the one you wrote), however it was a tedious work and non-adjustable circle.